# SeAuditPrivilege error

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

My WCF service has this config setting for Security Audit:

```
<serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Default" 
                      suppressAuditFailure="false" 
                      ServiceAuthorizationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" 
                      messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure"/>
```

When a method is invoked for this service locally using ASP.Net Dev Server, it results into this error:

```
    <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
           <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
           <Message>The process does not possess the 'SeAuditPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.</Message>
           <StackTrace>at System.IdentityModel.Privilege.EnableTokenPrivilege(SafeCloseHandle threadToken)
             ...
```

I am having Windows7 on my local machine.

Can anyone please guide what could be the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not re-ask questions simply because you haven't got an answer yet - http://stackoverflow.com/q/25193606/745969

Comment: Sure! I have deleted my old question now. I think I was providing too much detail to have anyone's attention.

Comment: Actually your old question was better - it had more information in it.  I'd delete this one and undelete your previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of 'SeAuditPrivilege' error, I had to change

```
auditLogLocation="Default"
```

to

```
auditLogLocation="Application"
```

I am having Windows7 and for some reason, it was not able to write to "Security Logs" which is default for Windows 7 as this link from MS suggests -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.auditloglocation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
Default

Specifies the default location, which is determined by the operating system. 
If writing to the Security log is supported (such as on Windows Vista and Windows 
Server 2003 and later platforms), the default log location is the Security log. 
Otherwise (such as in Windows XP SP2), the default log location is the Application log.
```

I had to change the value from "Default" to "Application" to make it work.

HTH.